# Tool to help measure web page elements

Tags: website-design

I'm wondering if there's a tool out there that can be used to measure all the elements of a web page. I find Chrome's element inspector very handy, and I'm curious if there is a tool that would enable me to measure each element of a web page at once. I tried using [Instant Wireframe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instant-wireframe/pmpmnmbgidlnoamkpmcikaejhmeldnha) but that seems to be broken. Does anyone know of any other design tools that may help? For any browser...

Example:

[image: Element measurements]

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Tool+to+help+measure+web+page+elements

Comment: Funny, but not helpful.

Comment: Ahh.,. but more effort than you've shown in your question. :) Seriously, have you tried anything there? There are Chrome extensions, Firefox Extensions, shareware... lots to choose from. Based on your question... it kind of looks like advertising for that particular extension. I'm *not* stating it is.. just that it looks like it since that's the **only** thing you mention and you provide a link to it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried a number of different extensions for both Chrome, and Firefox, but haven't found anything that suits the specific needs set out in my question. After reaching dead ends, I'm now asking here if anyone knows of a tool. Do you know of a tool that can do what is shown in my example?

Comment: The extension that I mentioned looks as though it would help, but as I mentioned in the question, it fails to work, it's a broken extension. I'm wondering if there are any functioning alternatives.

Comment: Why don't you develop a plugin yourself to do this?? :p

Comment: Why do you need to get all the measurements?

Comment: screenshot+photoshop?

Comment: Hi Bob, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please [edit] your question with the extensions you tried and why they didn't live up to your expectations? That way, it's way easier to find the right answer for you. Thanks! If you have any questions about this site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Web Developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) for chrome does this:

[image: example]

Comment: Oh yea. Forgot to say this earlier. I came up with a possible reason for why someone down voted. The screenshot you linked is for div order, not div dimensions. Though that option is visible in the screenshot... Also, to show image dimensions, you need to go to the image tab and similarly enable image dimensions separately.

Comment: Ah, I was on the rush and totally forgot the dimensions

but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Check out a Chrome extension called [Dimensions (demo too)](http://felixniklas.com/dimensions/), download [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dimensions/baocaagndhipibgklemoalmkljaimfdj).

[image]

Some info from the page:

> A tool for designers to measure screen dimensions
>
> ## Images & HTML Elements
>
> Measure between the following elements: images, input-fields, buttons, videos, gifs, text, icons. You can measure everything you see in the browser.
>
> ## Mockups
>
> Your designer handed you mockups as PNGs or JPEGs? Just drop them into Chrome, activate Dimensions and start measuring.
>
> ## Keyboard Shortcut
>
> For the best experience set a keyboard shortcut in the Extension Settings to quickly enable and disable Dimensions.
>
> ## Open Source
>
> Dimensions is Open Source and hosted on Github. Want to port it to Firefox? Go ahead and fork it. Pull requests are welcomed!

Comment: How does this tool "measure each element of a web page at once"?

Answer (score 1):

If the site loads jQuery, you can enter this in the Developer Console:

```
$.each($('*'), function(i, e) { console.log(i, $(e).width(), $(e).height(), e ); });
```

It gives you an indexed list, width and height of all items. Like always, when you hover an item in the list, the item get's highlighted.

Another nice tool to see size is the FireFox developer 3d view. It is not an add-on. It is build-in. You can see the size and nesting of elements. Choose Tools > Web Developer > Web Console. Click the gear icon. Select 3D view. An 3D icon is added next to the gear... Click it!

[image]

Comment: I feel like this isn't really answering the question well

Comment: I feel like this-isn't-really-answering-the-question-well-comments are not very constructive.